# RabbitMQ Multiple Unique Consumers on Windows Service

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, windows-services

I've searched StackOverflow and I don't think the other issues around multiple consumers match what I am trying.

I have a Windows service that starts and registers to monitor **two different** RabbitMQ queues.  If I only register it to listen to 1 queue, it works fine.  When I try to get it to listen to both queues, only the 2nd listener works.

```
var responseConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_responseChannel);

responseConsumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body);
    // PROCESS MESSAGE
    IssuerProcessor processor = new IssuerProcessor("Processed Message(" + pause + "ms) : ");

    Thread.Sleep(pause);

    var ret = processor.ProcessResponseMessage();
    Console.WriteLine("Processed message: " + ret);
    ulong deliveryTag = ea.DeliveryTag;

    _responseChannel.BasicAck(deliveryTag, false);
    Console.WriteLine("ACK RESPONSE Delivery Tag (" + deliveryTag.ToString() + "): " + ret);
}; // end requestConsumer.Received

_responseChannel.BasicConsume(queue: RESPONSE_QUEUE, autoAck: autoAck, consumer: responseConsumer);
```

The other consumer looks just like this one, but it listens to a different queue, using the same connection, with a different channel.

Here is the initialization for both:

```
_requestChannel = _connection.CreateModel();
_responseChannel = _connection.CreateModel();

_requestChannel.ExchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE, ExchangeType.Direct, true, false, null);
_requestChannel.QueueDeclare(queue: REQUEST_QUEUE, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
_requestChannel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
_requestChannel.QueueBind(REQUEST_QUEUE, EXCHANGE, REQUEST_QUEUE, null);

_responseChannel.ExchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE, ExchangeType.Direct, true, false, null);
_responseChannel.QueueDeclare(RESPONSE_QUEUE, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
_responseChannel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
_responseChannel.QueueBind(RESPONSE_QUEUE, EXCHANGE, RESPONSE_QUEUE, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the service was running on a single thread and it could not monitor both queues at the same time.

I just created two different Threads and started each consumer on a different Thread.

```
public void StartWorkerThreads()
{
    Thread receivingConsumerThread = new Thread(StartListenReceivingQueue);
    receivingConsumerThread.Start();

    Thread respondingConsumerThread = new Thread(StartListenRespondingQueue);
    respondingConsumerThread.Start();
}
```